# What is a solid approach for creating CRUD forms in React without the component turning into a mess?

Tags: reactjs, forms

What is a good approach to creating forms in React? More specifically, reusable form logic that handles Creating, Reading, Updating and Deleting records?

My approach so far has been to create a React state variable for each field in the form. Text inputs, checkboxes, selects, etc. Then I create a host of functions for getting an existing record, creating a new record, a React Memo to detect if the local copy of the data is not equal to the data pulled from the database (to enable a Save Changes button), etc.

This approach *works*, but it quickly turns a relatively small component into something hard to maintain, and I am having a hard time breaking out the logic into a reusable Component or Hook.

Comment: Form libraries usually make this a lot easier, they usually take an initial state and field updates work off names. You probably don't need to reinvent the wheel here unless you have some extra requirements that can't be met by what's already available. I'd look at building on top of something like react-final-form or react-hook-form.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I have taken a look at react-hook-form a bit, but haven't seen the way it would be used as a "one size fits all" for reading or updating existing data, only creating new data.. Do you have an example project or a solid video that would demonstrate this? Thanks again.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used react-hook-form, but if I remember correctly you should be able to provide initial values to the form using `useForm({ values: loadedDataHere })` and this should allow you to make your update functionality. At some point in time your code will know whether the action you wish to take is either an insert/update/delete/view and this could be passed through to your form as a prop. This could then be used to set readOnly states if it's a view / delete, or changing the form slightly between insert / update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rough and basic example of setting up a form that could be used for Insert / Update / Delete / View using `react-hook-form`.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { FC } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

// The example data object used by the form.
interface Model {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

// Insert form props
interface InsertFormProps {
  mode: 'Insert';
  model?: Model;
}

// Update form props
interface UpdateFormProps {
  mode: 'Update';
  model: Model;
}

// Delete form props
interface DeleteFormProps {
  mode: 'Delete';
  model: Model;
}

// View form props
interface ViewFormProps {
  mode: 'View';
  model: Model;
}

// Union form props
// Doing form props like this allows for
// different typing of each form mode.
// In this example this is used to make 'model'
// optional for 'Insert' but required for all
// other modes.
type FormProps =
  | InsertFormProps
  | UpdateFormProps
  | DeleteFormProps
  | ViewFormProps;

const Form: FC<FormProps> = ({ mode, model }) => {
  // Form hook, passing in model as the base value to use.
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
  } = useForm({ values: model });

  // configure read only conditions to pass to each input.
  const readOnly = mode === 'View' || mode === 'Delete' || isSubmitting;

  const onSubmit = (data: Model) => {
    switch (mode) {
      case 'Insert':
        console.log('Inserted', data);
        break;
      case 'Update':
        console.log('Updated', data);
        break;
      case 'Delete':
        console.log('Deleted', data);
        break;
    }
  };

  // layout form.
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <h1>{mode}</h1>
      { /* don't show ID on insert. */}
      {mode !== 'Insert' && (
        <div>
          ID: <input readOnly={readOnly} {...register('id')} />
        </div>
      )}
      <div>
        First Name: <input readOnly={readOnly} {...register('firstName')} />
      </div>
      <div>
        Last Name: <input readOnly={readOnly} {...register('lastName')} />
      </div>
      
      { 
        /* 
         * These could have easily been a condition on the value of the submit input, 
         * but this helps to should that you could change any part of the form layout
         * based on 'mode' or any other passed in property.
         */
      }
      {mode === 'Insert' && <input type="submit" value="Add" />}
      {mode === 'Update' && <input type="submit" value="Update" />}
      {mode === 'Delete' && <input type="submit" value="Delete" />}
    </form>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form mode="Insert" />
      <Form
        mode="Update"
        model={{
          id: 1,
          firstName: 'Test',
          lastName: 'Man',
        }}
      />
      <Form
        mode="Delete"
        model={{
          id: 1,
          firstName: 'Test',
          lastName: 'Man',
        }}
      />
      <Form
        mode="View"
        model={{
          id: 1,
          firstName: 'Test',
          lastName: 'Man',
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hc1c8b?file=App.tsx)